No puedo instanciar un vector de unique pointers usando la lista de inicializacion (C++)
El problema se me da con una línea de codigo muy simple y es la siguiente:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vector{
    std::make_unique<int>(5),
    std::make_unique<int>(4),
    std::make_unique<int>(3),
    std::make_unique<int>(2),
    std::make_unique<int>(1)
};

Cuando intento compilar falla. Sin embargo me funciona bien cuando intento con shared_ptr pero lo ideal en mi caso es usar unique_ptr.
El mensaje de error es muy grande y críptico pero en resumen es este:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
   90 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _Tp>::value,
      |                                                        ^~~~~

C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:115:28: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at(std::unique_ptr<int>*&, const std::unique_ptr<int>&)'
  115 |           std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:96:17: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
   96 |     -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:119:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
  119 |       ::new((void*)__p) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 


¿Cual sería el error que arroja?

mensaje de error agregado.

Los std::unique_ptr no son copiables.
De esa manera aseguran la propiedad de la memoria.
El error de compilación que obtienes es precisamente que estás tratando de usar el constructor copia:
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<>&)'

Así que uno pensaría que basta con usar std::move para asegurar que no realizamos copia de los argumentos al inicializar nuestro vector.
Esperando usar el constructor de movimiento.
Sin embargo la inicialización por lista de vectores siempre realiza una copia de sus elementos.
Esto es así porque se invoca al constructor de std::vector que recibe std::initializer_list.
La construcción de std::initializer_list se completa sin problemas.
La interfaz de este objeto devuelve un puntero constante (en tu caso const std::unique_ptr<int>*).
Debido a que un objeto const no se puede mover, se invocará al constructor copia.
Tendrás que inicializar tu vector de otra forma.
Por ejemplo usando push_back o emplace_back.

Podemos usar esta idea y definir una función para añadir los elementos uno a uno usando fold expressions de C++17:
template <typename T, typename... Args> 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> make_vector(Args&&... args)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
    data.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args))), ...);
    return data;
}

Así puedes usarla:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vector{
    make_vector<int>(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
};


Curiosamente solo no funciona cuando usas un list-initializer. Porque push_back y emplace_back funcionan correctamente
